# How to list raster bands?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, imagery

I am interested in looping through a directory and listing only the red bands (Band 1) from 4-band NAIP imagery.  From there I would like to mosaic all of the band 1 layers into a new single band raster image using [Mosaic to New Raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000098000000).  Is there a way to specify band 1 using `arcpy.ListRasters()` or should I find a new approach?

Comment: Switch to GDAL first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
import arcpy
bands = []
arcpy.env.workspace = #Set path to dir
for r in arcpy.ListRasters():
    rObject = arcpy.Describe(r)
    band1 = os.path.join(rObject.catalogPath,"bandx") #bandx = name of band to extract
    #outR = # full path to output raster
    #arcpy.CompositeBands_management(band1,outR) 
    bands.append(band1)

#do mosaic here outside loop.
```

The [Composite Bands](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Composite_Bands/00170000009p000000/) tool allows you to pull out bands from a multi band image.

Comment: +1 Excellent script help here--thanks.  Do you know if there is any way to bypass generating Composite Bands and pass a band1 list directly to Mosaic to New Raster?

Comment: @Aaron - instead of appending outR to the bands list, append band1 - this should give you a list of all Band1s, which you should be able to pass to the mosaic tool.